# Add custom site template to Template library, sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, site-template

I have created a custom site template and saved it on my desktop. i want to use this template as a standard template when creating Site collection by powershell code. How to save this template the template library on the farm to be able to use it.

i run this powershell to create site collection.

```
$Template = "BLANKINTERNET#0"

 New-SPSite -Url $url –ContentDatabase $ContentDatabase -Name $WebsiteName 
 Description $WebsiteDesc -Template $Template -OwnerAlias $PrimaryLogin
```

i want to change the template to my own created template, with other words, i want to be able to save my template on the farm/server and give it a name to be usable in all sitecollection creations.

Comment: how you created that template, a soultion?

Comment: also check this http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-create-sitecollection-web-using-custom-template/

Comment: i have a wsp file, that i have created from a site by using (save as template ). This file i want to make it standered and useable as from the template library, not as custom temp

Comment: once you add this in the farm( add-spsoution & install) then it will be available under the Custom heading of template selection.

Comment: Yeah, but isnt it possible to add this custom template under Collabration, Entreprise eller publishing heading ??

Comment: I dont think you can add in those categories. it will show under the custom tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the Solution package(wsp) into the farm and activate it and then that template will show under the custom tab of the template section.

you can import a WSP file directly into Visual Studio 2010, edit it, and create a new solution that does work.

check this one: http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/10/how-to-build-a-site-collection-template-from-a-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010/